# Liquibase insert select where not exists

Tags: postgresql, liquibase, liquibase-sql

I want to insert into `table1` multiple rows from `table2`. The problem is that I have a field of same name in `table2` and `table1` and I don't want to insert data if there's already a record with same value in this field. Now I have something like this:

```
insert into table1 (id, sameField, constantField, superFied)
select gen_random_uuid(), "sameField", 'constant', "anotherField"
from table2;
```

And I assume I need to do something like this:

```
insert into table1 (id, sameField, constantField, superFied)
select gen_random_uuid(), "sameField", 'constant', "anotherField"
from table2
where not exists ... ?
```

What I need to write instead of `?` if I want this logic: check if there's already same value in `sameField` in `table1` when selecting `sameField` from `table2`? DBMS is Postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a sub-query to see whether the record exists. You will need to define the column(s) which should be unique.

> ```
> create table table2(
> id varchar(100),
> sameField varchar(25),
> constant varchar(25),
> superField varchar(25)
> );
> insert into table2 values 
> (gen_random_uuid(),'same1','constant1','super1'),
> (gen_random_uuid(),'same2','constant2','super2')
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

2 rows affected

> 

> ```
> create table table1(
> id varchar(100),
> sameField varchar(25),
> constant varchar(25),
> superField varchar(25)
> );
> insert into table1 values
> (gen_random_uuid(),'same1','constant1','super1');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

1 rows affected

> 

> ```
> insert into table1 (id, sameField, constant, superField)
> select uuid_in(md5(random()::text || clock_timestamp()::text)::cstring),
>   t2.sameField, 'constant', t2.superField
> from table2 t2
> where sameField not in (select sameField from table1)
> ```

1 rows affected

> 

> ```
> select * from table1;
> select * from table2;
> ```
>
> ```
> id                                   | samefield | constant  | superfield
> :----------------------------------- | :-------- | :-------- | :---------
> 4cf10b1c-7a3f-4323-9a16-cce681fcd6d8 | same1     | constant1 | super1    
> d8cf27a0-3f55-da50-c274-c4a76c697b84 | same2     | constant  | super2    
>
> id                                   | samefield | constant  | superfield
> :----------------------------------- | :-------- | :-------- | :---------
> c8a83804-9f0b-4d97-8049-51c2c8c54665 | same1     | constant1 | super1    
> 3a9cf8b5-8488-4278-a06a-fd75fa74e206 | same2     | constant2 | super2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=7a33762688b1cac9a2c4233f7d8cc2b8)*

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you - I've modified the version in dbFiddle and it's working with `gen_random_uuid()`